# Conditional parsing on line number using awk

Tags: awk

This is easy but I just can't figure it out...

```
head file.txt
FN545816.1  EMBL    CDS     4188502 4189062 .   -   0   CDR20291_3537
FN545816.1  EMBL    gene    4189100 4189807 .   +   .   ID=gene-CDR20291_3538
FN545816.1  EMBL    CDS     4189100 4189807 .   +   0   CDR20291_3538
FN545816.1  EMBL    gene    4189839 4190024 .   -   .   ID=gene-CDR20291_3539
```

The file has some 8000 lines. I want to use `awk` and search for every line that has "+" in the 7th field and also "CDS" in the 3rd field, starting from line 3801  to the end.

This should be used as a condition:

```
awk '($7 ~ /+/ && $3 ~ /CDS/) {print $0}'
```

However, no idea how to instruct to start at specific line. I tried (unsuccessfully):

`awk 'BEGIN NR>=3801 {($7 ~ /+/ && $3 ~ /CDS/)} {print $0}'`

Thank you,
TP

Comment: No reason to monkey with a `BEGIN` block, just test that the currently processed line number `NR` is greater than `3801` with your other conditions. `awk 'NR>3801 && $7~/+/ && $3~/CDS/' file.txt` should do the trick

Comment: I knew it would be simple... It works, thank you.

Comment: @JNevill `$7~/+/` is a regexp repetition metachar at the start of a regexp and so is undefined behavior so YMMV regarding what any awk might do with that.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you want an exact match not regex?

```
$ awk 'NR>3800 && $7=="+" && $3=="CDS"' file
```